# Se reinicia interfaz al querer ingresar datos en TextFormField usando autentificación

Tags: firebase, flutter, autenticación

Realice una aplicación de prueba para probar la autentificación mediante **Firebase**, **Facebook**, **Google** y **Twitter**.
Una ves terminado y ver que funcionan en la aplicación de pruebas pase todo lo necesario para utilizarlo en otra aplicación pero resulta que en la otra aplicación utilizo `routes` para cambiar de interfaz,

El problema es que al querer ingresar correo o password la pantalla parpadea y parece que se reinicia la interfaz Inicio de sesión y no marca ningún error.
el Correo y el password los ingreso con un `TextFormField`

por lo tanto trate de adaptarlo de la siguiente manera

### Aplicación de prueba

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      auth: Auth(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Aplicación principal

```
class Aplicacion extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      auth: Auth(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          "/Principal": (BuildContext context) => Home(),
          "/Registro": (BuildContext context) => Registro(),
          "/Inicio de sesión": (BuildContext context) =>InicioSesion(),
          "/crear_datos": (BuildContext context) => Crear_datos(),
          "/Datos": (BuildContext context) => Datos(null)
        },
        home: Inicio(),
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Color(0xFF2F008E), accentColor: Color(0xFFDD303)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Lo que hice fue agregar la siguiente linea a mi aplicación principal**

```
Provider(
auth: Auth(),
child: MaterialApp(..
```

ya que de lo contrario al dar clic al `RaisedButton` me generaba un error de que `auth` era null o algo por el estilo, mi `RaisedButton` tiene lo siguiente

```
onPressed: () {
    // return InicioSesionPlussUltraPower();
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/Inicio de sesión");
},
```

### donde se ingresa los datos de correo y password

```
TextFormField(
    // validator: EmailValidator.validate,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        border:
            new OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        /* hasFloatingPlaceholder: true */),
    onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
  ),
  TextFormField(
    validator: PasswordValidator.validate,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Password",
        border:
            new OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        /* hasFloatingPlaceholder: true */),
    // obscureText: true,
    onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extrae las paginas o widgets que creaste en una variable para evitar que se esten recreando a cada cambio, algo así:

```
class Aplicacion extends StatelessWidget {

  final home = Home();
  final registro = Registro();
  final inicioSesion = InicioSesion();
  final crearDatos = Crear_datos();
  final datos = Datos(null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      auth: Auth(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          "/Principal": (BuildContext context) => home,
          "/Registro": (BuildContext context) => registro,
          "/Inicio de sesión": (BuildContext context) =>inicioSesion,
          "/crear_datos": (BuildContext context) => crearDatos,
          "/Datos": (BuildContext context) => datos
        },
        home: Inicio(),
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Color(0xFF2F008E), accentColor: Color(0xFFDD303)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```